# How to create unique constraints on AgensGraph

Tags: agens-graph

I want to use "id" property as primary key on label.

```
agens=# create vlabel v;
CREATE VLABEL
agens=# create (:v{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# create (:v{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
```

But, I don't know grammar for create constraint.

How to create unique constraints on AgensGraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unique property index on AgensGraph.

```
agens=# create (:v{id:1});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 1, INSERT EDGE 0)
agens=# create unique property index on v(id);
CREATE PROPERTY INDEX
agens=# create (:v{id:1});
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "v_id_idx"
DETAIL:  Key ((properties.'id'::text))=(1) already exists.
```